# Image processing in NI myrio FPGA

Tags: image-processing, fpga

I am using NI Myrio FPGA to do image processing. With the help of NI Vision Assistant 2014, i am able to get the image from usb webcam. I want to use FPGA to convert the image to HSV. However the functions provided in NI Vision Assistant only allow me to get either H, S, or V image at once.

In order to solve it, i try to create one more FIFO to store the image. Here is my FPGA coding.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx4sj3hshrd6QVUtUS05eVloOTA

However, I do not know how to access these FIFO. Here is Labview coding.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx4sj3hshrd6b0VsSEY2U0h1VFk/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx4sj3hshrd6MGd2SzMtS3BkYjg/view?usp=sharing

All these coding are actually generated by NI Vision Assistant and i cant find where can specify which FIFO i am accessing. Any can help me?